# Lines in monitor since installed new graphic card

Tags: display, graphics-card, stripe

I installed a Geforce RTX 3070 graphic card on my PC and when I restart the PC, all I can see on the monitor is stripes (see image). The PC has a 650w power supply, an Asus VG248QG monitor and an Asus Tuf Gaming Z590-plus motherboard. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See the manual for the card and check with GeForce support.

Comment: What image? Seems like you've missed something.